# How best to display a tree or trees of cousins?

Tags: chart-type

How can I best display all my first and second cousins, in a large printable chart, that we can reference at family gatherings?  Ideally for two people to quickly see their relationship.

I know I can print several descendancy charts, but then it becomes awkward to find a chart with each person's name on it, if at all.

Ideally, I'd also like to include my kids and my nieces and nephews (not necessarily all my cousins' kids and nieces and nephews, unless that was easily doable).

I'm happy to print something that is 4 feet by 4 feet if that's what it takes.  And I don't need something glamorous nor wordy; names, birth/death dates and connecting lines is good enough.

I'm aware that showing the connections could be problematic but hoping that this has been solved already and I'm just unaware.

Answer (score 1):

The [Family Historian](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) program has a diagram that prints everyone in the database and will output it as a pdf file for printing on a large scale printer. However, as you have already stated, depending on the number of individuals involved it may well be a very complicated diagram. There is a free 30 day trial of the program and it does allow the import of a gedcom file and so you could try it out for yourself to see if it is suitable.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score -1):

Gramps and the Graph View addon can show all connected people and you can save it to svg file.

https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Addon:Graph_View

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your answer could be improved by showing how the OP could display the diagram at a family gathering. Someone who hasn't made a display chart yet won't understand the significance of saving a diagram to an SVG file.

Comment: You can open a SVG file in browser then print it like a normal webpage.

Comment: Please add that to your answer for the people who don't know already. Plus, this still doesn't address the question of how to display the chart for a family gathering.  What does the OP need to know if taking the SVG file to a print shop?

Comment: Have you ever checked the link I provided?
It already shows every one connected with you.
You just have to print it, no special actions needed.